# Swift extension methods not showing up in obj c framework?

Tags: ios9

I've built an obj-c framework and I'm trying to extend my model using Swift 2.0. The file hierarchy looks like:

Class.h

Class.m

Class.Swift

The Class.Swift has a method: indexLocation

When trying to call this in the Class.m file

> [self indexLocation];

It can't find the method. Are there any additional steps I need to follow so that my implementation file can see the extension method?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I needed to import my frameworks header file in order for my .m file to find the methods.

In .m file:

```
#import <ProductModuleName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h>
```